# MySQL Average temperature specifying number of days

Tags: mysql, average, temperature

I have a table called data with columns:

- date [timestamp]
- temperature [int(11)]
- humidity [int(11)]

(for example ... date: 2016-06-11 10:07:22, temperature: 22, humidity: 50)

I get a new entry every 60 seconds.

Im wondering if its possible to define a query that will return the average temperature and humidity of every hour for a specified number of days. I need the hour average for yesterday (1 day), last week (last 7 days) and last month (last 30 days).

Comment: That query will be very slow in all cases... But it will be something like: `SELECT AVG(temperature), DATE(date), HOUR(date) FROM data GROUP BY DATE(date), HOUR(date)`

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for ... When you get to see it, things make sense, but i couldnt figure it up !!

Comment: If that answer suits you, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an average value per each hour, we need to `GROUP BY` the rows by the day + hour.

Sample query:

```
 SELECT AVG(temperature), DATE(date), HOUR(date) FROM data GROUP BY DATE(date), HOUR(date)
```

Comment: Based on Marki555 respond this is what i finally did: SELECT AVG(temperature) `avgtemp`, AVG(humidity) `avghum`, DATE(date) `day`, HOUR(date) `hour` FROM data WHERE date >= now() - INTERVAL 7 DAY GROUP BY day, hour ORDER BY date DESC;    THANKS !!!

Comment: ... just wondering if its easy to change the query to do the same average but for every 6-12 hours .... when i draw a whole month of info in a chart it looks really clogged

Comment: Yes, you just need to just specify which rows will be "collapsed" (grouped) into one... for example `FLOOR(HOUR(date)/12)` will make it every 12 hours (first 12 hours will output 0, remaining 12 hours will output 1).